# how to implement linkedin like animation (popup like , celebrate, support etc zoom-in zoom-put animation

Tags: animation, linkedin-api

## https://snack.expo.dev/@mr.paresh.chavda/likeanimation

Implementing a LinkedIn-like animation in React Native involves creating a card-like component that expands when clicked and collapses when clicked again. Here's a basic example of how you can achieve this:

how to create please help me